# Pass props / function to InnerBlocks

Tags: block-editor

I have a situation where i want to pass props to `InnerBlocks` just like I would be able to pass props to child components. The situation is, that I have a parent block that has a function to update its height, based on some InnerBlocks and their content / settings.

I want to call that function, when a user clicks the child block.

e.g.

```
<div onClick={ parent.updateHeight }> content </div>
```

How can that be achieved? I know that parent and child attributes are accessible with `select` calls but can I also pass functions?

Comment: Normally you wouldn't do this, is this related to the Q with swiper slides in blocks? Have you considered doing this with CSS and a HTML class on the parent block? Then used an attribute to control which HTML class ( e.g. `slider-tall` `slider-short` etc? )

Comment: Hey @TomJNowell you are everywhere. It is related but not possible with css. Swiper needs to calculate it's height dynamically sometimes with the `swiper.updateAutoHeight` function. In gutenberg I would need to call that when new child blocks are added / the height of a slide changes.

Comment: I indeed found a workaround with css. However the question remains for other general use cases.